# Multiple before() or beforEach() in mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, bdd, supertest

I need to do multiple async calls in before() hook in mocha. I need to delete a user, then signup , verify email  and finally login to get token to authenticate all other test cases. Here is my code snippet :

```
    const userInfo = {
        "password": "pass123",
        "email": "test@email.com",
    };

    var token = '' , userId = '';

    before((done) => {
        // Delete the  user if already exists
        User.remove({
                email: userInfo.email
            }).then((res) => {
              //  console.log(res.result);
            })
            .end(done);
        done();
    });


    before((done) => {
        request(app)
            .post('/api/users')        
            .send(userInfo)
            .expect(200)
            .expect((res) => {        
            })
            .end(done);
    });

    before((done) => {
        User.findOne({
                email: userInfo.email
            }).then((res) => {            
                userId = res._id;
                request(app)
                    .post('/api/users/verify-email')
                    .send({'token' : userId})
                    .expect(200)
                    .expect((res) => {                
                    })
                    .end(done);
            })
            .end(done);
        done();
    });
```

Here these calls are not executing in sequence. I need to fetch userId before verifying the email, but I am getting below error:

```
POST /api/users/verify-email 401 4.082 ms - 45
    1) "before all" hook
```

Comment: Although question is not clear. But **Yes** you can put multiple `breforeEach`. You can add more details and code in your question.

Answer (score 13):

First of all, yes, mocha allows multiple before hooks and guarantees that they are called in the right order. To make sure of this you could run this snippet.

```js
'use strict';

const results = [];
const assert = require('assert');

before(done => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`First 'before'`);
        results.push(1);
        done(); //Will be called last
    }, 1000)
});

before(done => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`Second 'before'`);
        results.push(2); //Will be called second
        done();
    }, 300)
});

before(done => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`Third 'before'`);
        results.push(3); //Will be called first
        done();
    }, 100)
});

describe('Before hooks order', () => {
    it('should before hooks sequentially', () => {
        //Check if the hooks were called in the right order anyway
        assert.deepEqual(results, [1, 2, 3]);
    });
});
//Output is:
// First 'before'
// Second 'before'
// Third 'before'
```

But to make this happen you need to call done() only when all the async operations are done to let mocha know that the hook is completed and it should run the next one.

Also there is a rule that any Node.js callback must be called only once. So here are a couple of fixes:

```js
before((done) => {
    // Delete the  user if already exists
    User
        .remove({
            email: userInfo.email
        })
        .then((res) => {
            //  console.log(res.result);
        })
        .end(done);
    //Do not call done here() because User.remove have only started
    //We need to wait until it finishes. Done will be called in .end method
    // done();
});

before((done) => {
    //All good here
    request(app)
        .post('/api/users')
        .send(userInfo)
        .expect(200)
        .expect((res) => {
        })
        .end(done);
});

before((done) => {
    User.findOne({
        email: userInfo.email
    }).then((res) => {
        userId = res._id;
        //You need a return statement here so the outer promise waits
        //Until the internal call finishes
        return request(app)
            .post('/api/users/verify-email')
            .send({'token': userId})
            .expect(200)
            .expect((res) => {
            });
    //We must not call callback multiple times, so remove this.
    // .end(done);
    })
    //Now this 'end' will happen only after both calls finish
    .end(done);

    //Remove this please, for the same reason as with the first 'before'
    // done();
});
```

Please check it out. I'm not able to run your code (don't have your api), so please let me know of any problems.

Comment: I am getting below error after removing done():    "before all" hook:
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

Comment: @GirishGupta ok, so please comment out all the 'befores' except the one that fails (I guest the first one), and then please check if console.log(res.result); (currently commented) is logging something. If it does try removing .end(done) and call done() inside .then() (after log).

Comment: @GirishGupta that's a different problem. Call mocha with `--timeout 10000` or some higher value if your upstreams take a while to complete.